# Loading images dynamically with Parceljs

Tags: parceljs

Is it possible to load images dynamically with parceljs bundler, when image names are not known at build time

Is there something similar to webpack's [require.context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context) in parcel

Code Snippet (using React and Parcel)
This works fine

```
...
<img src={require('../images/Image4.jpg')}/>
...
```

But if expression is used, it throws "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module"

```
...
var imgName = "Image4";
...
...
<img src={require('../images/' + imgName + '.jpg')}/>
...
```

[Image - Uncaught Error: Cannot find module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzn39.png)

So, am i doing this wrong? is there any other way to do this with parcel

Comment: Share what you have done so far (code, errors etc) and where you are having the problem.

Answer (score 11):

I dont think this is currently possible, one hacky way iv got it around it, is to do this :

```
import icons from './assets/icons/**'

const icon_file_name = 'user'
const specificIcon = icons[`${icon_file_name}.png`]

<img src={specificIcon} />
```

Comment: Tried this but I'm getting an error: Data must be a string or a buffer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Based on [Luke Robertson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2028456/luke-robertson) answer tried the similar hack and it worked for me:

```
import images from '../assets/cover/images/*.jpg';
const file_name = "file-name"
<img src=`${images[file_name]}` />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is annoying. But I came up with an implementation that allows us to load dynamic images during run time in parcel with react.

For the below implementation to work, have the latest version of Parcel (mine is 2.11.0).

.parcelrc file

```
This is to let parcel know that we are using glob patterns.

{
  "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
  "resolvers": [
    "@parcel/resolver-glob",
    "..."
  ]
}
```

In your component

```
import png from "../assets/*.png";
import jpg from "../assets/*.jpg";
import jpeg from "../assets/*.jpeg";
import webp from "../assets/*.webp";

const FunctionalComponent = (props) => {
    const { image } = props; // getting dynamic images as prop.

    const obj = Object.assign({}, png, jpg, jpeg, webp);
    const img = image?.split(".").shift(); // considering the value of image is "image.jpg"

    return (
        <div>
            {image && (
                <div className="img-background">
                    {[obj].map((data) => {
                        return Object.keys(data).map((val) => {
                            if (val === img) {
                               // this refers to the minfied version of the image by parcel.
                                return <img key={val} src={obj[val]} alt={val} />;
                            }
                        });
                    })}
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default FunctionalComponent;
```